# Java jdbc SQLException in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

When I click my previous button, my textfields are not populated with the values from the DB. It gives me the error of java.sql.SQLException:

> Column 'PassengerName' not found.

The column `PassengerName` exists in my DB. Can someone tell me what is wrong please?

Here's my code:

```
public PaymentForm() {

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        stt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM payment");

        rs = stt.executeQuery();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection Successful to Database", "Success", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    }catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error in connecting to db", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    initialize();
    }
}

    JButton btnPrev = new JButton("Previous");
    btnPrev.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

             try {
             if (rs.previous()) {

                    pass.setSelectedItem(rs.getString("PassengerName"));

                    int d = rs.getInt("InvoiceNo");
                    in.setText(String.valueOf(d));
                    int d2 = rs.getInt("CardNo");
                    cn.setText(String.valueOf(d2));
                    double pr = rs.getDouble("Price");
                    tp.setText(String.valueOf(pr));

                    nc.setText(rs.getString("Name"));
             }else {
                 rs.next();
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No more records");
             }

             }catch(Exception e1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
                    e1.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: Could you share the query as well, or the `Statement` you use for creating `rs`?

Comment: Check your select SQL query. Make sure u have included PassengerName column in select column list. also check with database table & make sure u don't have any typo in ur select SQL query.

Comment: I have select * from payment ! 

There's no typo, nothing :/

Comment: If you comment out the line with `pass.setSelectedItem(...` does everything work okay? I.e. is the problem only occurring on that one column?

Comment: The problem persists with all the columns ! 
I have even commented each line, but the problem persists

Comment: Check the column names you're getting from [the resultset metadata](http://stackoverflow.com/a/696794/905488), e.g. using a debugger.

Comment: @Nilesh Bhunjun I am telling u to check the "PassengerName" which u have used to get the value from resultset and the actual column name in the table are same or not. Could u plz share with us the table structure?

Answer (score 1):

Your query doesn't include that column...when you do getString on the resultset you will get the error.

As a side note: you can read column values from ResultSet using directly getString(...) even if the underlying type isn't a string

Comment: I have the following column names in my table: 
The exact words.

InvoiceNo  PassengerName   CardNo  Name  Price

Comment: No not in your table i mean in your SELECT statement. You're not seldcting that column

Comment: SELECT (column names) FROM (table) WHERE (condition) but you should already do something like that...the problem is that (column names) doesn't mention PassengerName

Comment: Nope. It does not work.. However when I implemented the Next button functionality. Instead of looping over each record, it directly says no more records without displaying anything on my JTextfields.

Comment: It's a bit hard to talk widely in this context...but I see some design issue in your app: a previous or next gui button that directly triggers an iteration over an open resultset? Your client sounds really coupled  with the database, and in general this isn't a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT PassengerName FROM payment

try to execute the above statement in mysql directly and see if this give you result

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use query with * selector in code like **'SELECT * FROM payment'**, just list all needed column like '**'SELECT ID, PassengerName  FROM payment'**'.
2. Make sure that table payment has column named **'PassengerName'**

Answer (score 0):

I have to create an update table method (). 
In the method I select * from the table. 
Then I call the method after the initialise method ().