# How to verify the existence of a column in table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, sqlexception

I want to check if `DateTimeCheck` column exists before reading its value:

```
private void parseResultSet(ResultSet ride) {
  if (ride.getDate("DateTimeCheck") != null)
            this.RideDate = df.format(ride.getDate("DateTimeCheck"));

}
```

This code still provides this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'DateTimeCheck' not found.
```

How to fix it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696782/retrieve-column-names-from-java-sql-resultset

Comment: Of course, you do know that you shouldn't use `SELECT *` in queries in code, right? So your code that created the `ResultSet` would know if it queried the column in question. See [What is the reason not to use select *?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-is-the-reason-not-to-use-select)

Comment: @Andreas I don't see a select * anywhere, even old version of question. I can be exceedingly dense, please forgive.

Comment: @Drew You don't see it because the code that produces the `ResultSet` is not posted in the question. That code *may* very well do a `SELECT *`.

Comment: so I don't get why the `you know that you shouldn't use` part. You jumping to conclusions bro? Even if he did, do a select *, huh ?  @Andreas, how does that even remotely help him ... idk

Comment: @Andreas: Thanks for this comment. No, I don't use SELECT *. I have two SELECT and use the same function parseResultSet for both of them

Comment: Mureinik is our on call mysql master at the moment. Follow those that have tag rank

Comment: @KlausosKlausos Instead of having to scan the result columns using `getMetaData()`, I'd suggest that you pass a parameter to `parseResultSet` to let it know whether it's parsing column set 1 or column set 2, e.g. a `boolean hasDateTimeCheck` or whatever name fits your more complex scenario.

Comment: @Andreas: Ok, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`ResultSetMetadata`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) to check for the column's existence.

```
private static boolean hasColumn (RestultSet rs, String column) {
    RestulSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
    int colCount = md.getColumnCount();
    for (int i = 1; i <= colCount; ++i) { // Note that column indexes are 1-based
        if (column.equalsIgnoreCase(rs.getColumnName(i))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```