# JMeter, how to write JDBC query results as csv, including column names?

Tags: jmeter

I would like to write the results of my JDBC query as csv file, including a line with the names of the columns.

I am able to write results by defining a JDBC PreProcessor in which I assign the `Result variable name` to `resultSet`, and a JSR223 PreProcessor where I include the below script to write to csv.

However, the variable returned by `vars.getObject("resultSet");` is a `Collection`, so I am unable to get the column name information. Is it possible to pass the `ResultSet` object to the JSR223 PreProcessor so that I can export column names?

```
resultSet = vars.getObject("resultSet");
result = new StringBuilder();

//for (int i = 0; i <= resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
//  result.append(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(i));
//  result.append(',');
//}
//result.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

for (Object row : resultSet ) {
    iter = row.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        pair = iter.next();
        result.append(pair.getValue());
        result.append(",");
    }
    result.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}

org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("/tmp/data", "results.csv"), result.toString(), "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `resultSet` **already has** column names. As per [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) article:

> Regarding working with the `Result Variable Name`, as mentioned previously, it is an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) of [`HashMaps`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), one map per result set row. The map entries count depends on the **column values, the map entry name will be the same as the result set column name**, and the map entry value will be the value itself.

So you need to amend your code to read the column names as well, something like:

```
resultSet = vars.getObject("resultSet")
result = new StringBuilder()

def randomRow = resultSet.get(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(0,resultSet.size()))

randomRow.each { k, v -> 
    result.append("${k}").append(",")
}
result.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"))

for (Object row : resultSet ) {
    iter = row.entrySet().iterator()
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        pair = iter.next()
        result.append(pair.getValue())
        result.append(",")
    }
    result.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"))
}

org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("foo.csv"), result.toString(), "UTF-8")
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense... but is it possible to get the ResultSetMetadata? Would also be useful to know the column datatype

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of CSV libraries in Java, Apache Commons CSV, https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/, OpenCSV, http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/.

Personally instead of trying to run a generic SQL statement such as `SELECT * FROM table_name;` I'd be specific in stating what columns you actually need. Then you know what column names you are going to be adding to the CSV file.

If you do want to create something generic that also can parse the names of the columns, this answer may provide what you're looking for - [Retrieve column names from java.sql.ResultSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696782/retrieve-column-names-from-java-sql-resultset)

Comment: The issue is that the resultSet object provided by `vars.getObject("resultSet");` is of type `ArrayList` not of type `ResultSet`