# How to print column name and data from DB, using java

Tags: java, jdbc

Can anyone suggest hot to print column name and value in output in console:

I have below code which only prints the value of the column, but i need to print value with correspondence column name as well:

```
import java.io.*;  
import java.sql.*;  

public class RetrieveFile {  
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@123.32.23.123:8080/orcl", "test1", "******");

            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from MSG where MID='1234'");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            try {
                printResultColumns(rs);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }

            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void printResultColumns(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException, IOException {
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = resultSet.getMetaData();
    int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

    while (resultSet.next()) {
        // you get a single result row in here, not the entire ResultSet
        for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
            switch (rsmd.getColumnType(i)) {
            case Types.VARCHAR:
            case Types.LONGVARCHAR:
            case Types.CHAR:
                System.out.println(resultSet.getString(i));
                break;
            case Types.DOUBLE:
                System.out.println(resultSet.getDouble(i));
                break;
            case Types.INTEGER:
                System.out.println(resultSet.getInt(i));
                break;
            case Types.DATE:
                System.out.println(resultSet.getDate(i).toString());
                break;
            case Types.TIMESTAMP:
                System.out.println(resultSet.getTimestamp(i).toString());
                break;
            case Types.BOOLEAN:
                System.out.println(resultSet.getBoolean(i));
                break;
            case Types.DECIMAL:
            case Types.NUMERIC:
                System.out.println(resultSet.getBigDecimal(i));
                break;
            default:
                //System.out.println(rsmd.getColumnClassName(i)



            }
        }
    }


}
    }
```

Current Output:-
null
1961108001406E00
389
OUR
NOW
USD

Expected Output:-
Col1-null
Col2-1961108001406E00
Col3-389
Col4-OUR
Col5-NOW
Col6-USD

```
OR Expected Out put:-
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  Col6
-----------------------------------
null  1961   389  our   now    usd
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve column names from java.sql.ResultSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696782/retrieve-column-names-from-java-sql-resultset)

Comment: you need some formatting while printing data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it by the column name stored in the `ResultSetMetaData`:

```java
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = resultSet.getMetaData();
int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

while (resultSet.next()) {
    // you get a single result row in here, not the entire ResultSet
    for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
        int type = rsmd.getColumnType(i);
        String typeName = rsmd.getColumnTypeName(i);
        String name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
        String value;
        switch (type) {
        case Types.VARCHAR:
            value = resultSet.getString(i) == null ? "null" : resultSet.getString(i);
            System.out.println(name + ": " + value);
            break;
        case Types.DOUBLE:
            value = resultSet.getString(i) == null ? "null" : String.valueOf(resultSet.getDouble(i));
            System.out.println(name + " [" + typeName + "]: " + value);
            break;
        case Types.INTEGER:
            value = resultSet.getString(i) == null ? "null" : String.valueOf(resultSet.getInt(i));
            System.out.println(name + " [" + typeName + "]: " + value);
            break;
        case Types.DATE:
            value = resultSet.getString(i) == null ? "null" : String.valueOf(resultSet.getDate(i).toString());
            System.out.println(name + " [" + typeName + "]: " + value);
            break;
        case Types.TIMESTAMP:
            value = resultSet.getString(i) == null ? "null" : resultSet.getTimestamp(i).toString();
            System.out.println(name + " [" + typeName + "]: " + value);
            break;
        case Types.BOOLEAN:
            value = resultSet.getString(i) == null ? "null" : (resultSet.getBoolean(i) ? "true" : "false");
            System.out.println(name + " [" + typeName + "]: " + value);
            break;
        case Types.DECIMAL:
        case Types.NUMERIC:
            value = resultSet.getString(i) == null ? "null" : resultSet.getBigDecimal(i).toString();
            System.out.println(name + " [" + typeName + "]: " + value);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("The column type (" + rsmd.getColumnTypeName(i)
                    + " for column " + rsmd.getColumnName(i) + ", Label: " + rsmd.getColumnLabel(i)
                    + ") is currently not supported in method \"printResultColumns\".\nAdd it as case there.");
        }

    }
}
```

If you have given the column some aliases, maybe use `getColumnLabel` instead (see `default`, it is used there).

For the case you want to output something like your table, iterate the meta data for the column names and print them once before printing the values of the result rows.

Comment: you beauty, but one issue its failing were there is longchar data type.

Comment: @Routray Does it throw an `Exception` or does it print weird things? What's the *fail* exactly?

Comment: i have added case as "case Types.LONGVARCHAR:
           System.out.println(rsmd.getColumnName(i) + ": " + resultSet.getLong(i));" but its printing as datatype+column name+column name

Comment: @Routray If you don't have given the columns aliases in SQL, `getColumnName` and `getColumnLabel` are likely to return the same `String`, so just use one of them or give each column an alias (which is not possible via `SELECT * FROM ...`, it should then be `SELECT id AS identification, someColumn AS SomeValue`. Then you will get different return values from those methods.

Comment: @Routray Btw, `LONGVARCHAR` maps to `String`, so you cannot do `resultSet.getLong(i)` on it!

Comment: thanks for the response, after specifying alias in column name it's works fine...but there is a column its repeating two times, any clue why it's behaving like that as                                                                                             FEE: 389
FEE: 389

Comment: @Routray sorry, not really... What type does that column have?

Comment: now it's works fine, issue was i have missed a break in between. Thanks

Comment: sure, how to handle NULL value, if the column contains NULL value i want print that as well.

Comment: @Routray You have to check for `null` and I would use a String variable to store the result or `"null"`. Then use that variable for printing.

Comment: i think we can't used duplicate case, although we are saving different value, can you please pass some code. Sorry for asking too many...

Comment: @Routray see last edit, just updated code and nothing else.

Comment: i have observed a issue if there is a column type longchar, there its not printing the column value, its print only the column heading. Any solution for this?Thanks

Comment: @Routray sorry, never heard of a type `LONGCHAR`, but `LONGVARCHAR`. Are you sure it is `LONGCHAR`? It doesn't seem to make much sense, because a `CHAR` is a single character. What would be the use of a `LONGCHAR` (long char) then?

Comment: extremely sorry, its LONGVARCHAR.

Comment: @Routray I don't really know, many documents say it is treated as `String` like `VARCHAR`. You can add a `case LONGVARCHAR:` above the `case VARCHAR:` as you have done. Maybe a special thing about the database engine.

Comment: thanks for the response. I have added this into the code"case Types.LONGVARCHAR:" but still its not retrieving the value of the code. its printing like CHARMIDMID(2 time column name with datatype prifix)

Comment: @Routray What a value is in that column? You can have a look at [how mapping types is done in JDBC](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/629/jdkdocs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.doc.html). You may find that `LONGVARCHAR` *can* be retrieved as `String`, but does not have a recommended type.

Comment: thanks for the input. Now this issue solved, as i was missing CHAR data type in CASE. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use metadata of result set.

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a, b, c FROM TABLE2");
 ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
 String name = rsmd.getColumnName(1);
```

Comment: thanks for the response, if you see my implementation, i have also used metadata, but only values are getting print not column name.

Comment: You have not use getColumnName() method

Answer (score 0):

***Issue Resolved:-***

```
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = resultSet.getMetaData();
int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

while (resultSet.next()) {
    // you get a single result row in here, not the entire ResultSet
    for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
        int type = rsmd.getColumnType(i);
        String typeName = rsmd.getColumnTypeName(i);
        String name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
        String value;
        switch (type) {
        case Types.VARCHAR:
            value = resultSet.getString(i) == null ? "null" : resultSet.getString(i);
            System.out.println(name + ": " + value);
            break;
        case Types.DOUBLE:
            value = resultSet.getString(i) == null ? "null" : String.valueOf(resultSet.getDouble(i));
            System.out.println(name + " [" + typeName + "]: " + value);
            break;
        case Types.INTEGER:
            value = resultSet.getString(i) == null ? "null" : String.valueOf(resultSet.getInt(i));
            System.out.println(name + " [" + typeName + "]: " + value);
            break;
        case Types.DATE:
            value = resultSet.getString(i) == null ? "null" : String.valueOf(resultSet.getDate(i).toString());
            System.out.println(name + " [" + typeName + "]: " + value);
            break;
        case Types.TIMESTAMP:
            value = resultSet.getString(i) == null ? "null" : resultSet.getTimestamp(i).toString();
            System.out.println(name + " [" + typeName + "]: " + value);
            break;
        case Types.BOOLEAN:
            value = resultSet.getString(i) == null ? "null" : (resultSet.getBoolean(i) ? "true" : "false");
            System.out.println(name + " [" + typeName + "]: " + value);
            break;
        case Types.DECIMAL:
        case Types.NUMERIC:
            value = resultSet.getString(i) == null ? "null" : resultSet.getBigDecimal(i).toString();
            System.out.println(name + " [" + typeName + "]: " + value);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("The column type (" + rsmd.getColumnTypeName(i)
                    + " for column " + rsmd.getColumnName(i) + ", Label: " + rsmd.getColumnLabel(i)
                    + ") is currently not supported in method \"printResultColumns\".\nAdd it as case there.");
        }

    }
}
```